# Does ColdFusion throw error if function is not camelCase?

Tags: coldfusion, camelcasing

I am trying to investigate a bug and am not super familiar with ColdFusion.  There is a function call to `isdefined()`, which I believe should be `isDefined()`.  What behavior does ColdFusion take if it runs into this kind of case discrepancy with a built-in function?  Does it return truthy? Does it skip the statement?

The traceback shows the error coming from a line within this `<cfif isdefined(...)>` statement, so I'm wondering if the incorrect casing could be affecting this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: ColdFusion is not case sensitive so case should make no difference. Note `isDefined` requires a string not a variable. So if you want to know if the function/variable named `myFunction` is defined, you would call `<cfif isDefined('myFunction')>`. I've made the dumb mistake before so just FYI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Leeish said. Function calls are NOT case sensitive. See [CF documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fbd.html), the correct usage is  `IsDefined("variable_name")`

If all else fails, post a bigger block of the code here and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Thank you, and thank you Leeish for the tip!  The error report was not related to the `isdefined()` statement, I just wanted to check to see if that was part of what was causing it.  I will continue my investigation elsewhere.